# Get Angular Scope in PageMod Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm making a Firefox addon using FF 44.0a2 Developer Edition and the Firefox Addon SDK. I am injecting an AngularJS app into the page DOM using a pageMod content script. Later on in the file, I am trying to get a hold of the AngularJS App scope object so that I can use it to make some API calls. Here's how I am trying to do it

```
    var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("ngApp")).scope();      
    console.log(scope);
```

If I type this into the browser console, it gives me the complete scope,however when I do this in my pageMod content script, this returns `null` even though the app is injected? Could someone please point out my mistake? I'd appreciate any help on the matter

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't get it on the `ngApp` you should get it from the element that has a controller attached to it.

I used angular in my firefox addons a lot, I now switched to React because its much more performant.

But here is how I would get and access the scope, injector etc:

Here is the ngApp: https://github.com/Noitidart/ZooniverseXpert/blob/master/app.xhtml#L15

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="zooniversexpert">
    <body ng-controller="BodyController as BC">
```

And here is me getting the scope: https://github.com/Noitidart/ZooniverseXpert/blob/master/resources/scripts/app.js#L46-L47

```
    var gAngBody = angular.element(document.body);
    gAngScope = gAngBody.scope();
```

This is a firefox addon that is more in-depth angular usage - https://github.com/Noitidart/MailtoWebmails/ - it uses directrives from files, injector, scope, sanitization, and some other stuff.

Comment: Since you've used firefox addons, how'd you get the page DOM element in the pageMod content script? Cause it seems thats the issue for me. I cant seem to find that.
I've tried `document`, `window`, `unsafeWindow`, `window.content`, `window.document`. The closest I get is with `unsafeWindow.console.log(document)` but I dont understand how to save this obj in a variab;e :(

Comment: what you've suggested, I already tried and it didnt work out :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean how to get the dom element into the pagemod content script. You inject that content script, so that script can access everything within. It really should work, I used it extensively in the past 6 months.

Comment: yes. I've injected the pagemod content script into the page dom. But `document`, `window`, `unsafeWindow`, `window.content`, `window.document`. all return either `null` or `undefined` any idea why?